# How can I force changing the keyboard layout in Linux in IDE?

Tags: linux, keyboard, ide, debian

When I upgraded to debian 12, I have new problem with jetbreans and netbeans ide, These java application can't change keyboard layouts, when I change keyboard layout to Swedish for one moment then back to English immediately!

So my problem is: I can't change keyboard layout in all IDE's based on java, how to fix this problem in ide?

BTW, I flowed this topic and other topics look like this:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-254960/Keyboard-shortcuts-dont-follow-layout-changes-under-ubuntu-gnome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depends on you NVIDIA drivers, I have write about this on [my life blog](https://4xmen.ir/%D9%85%D8%B4%DA%A9%D9%84-%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B6-%D8%B2%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%B1-jetbreans-ide-gnome-40-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%88%DA%A9%D8%B3-%D8%A8%D8%A7-nvidia/)

Summery

There is no usual solution to fix this problem completely, but You, can use my alternative solution:

test `setxkbmap`

```
$ sudo apt-get install x11-xkb-utils
$ setxkbmap -query

rules: evdev
model: pc105
layout: us,ir
```

then you can change you language manual: ( you can replace your language here like `sv` or `ru` instead `ir`)

```
$ setxkbmap us,ir
$ setxkbmap ir,us
```

Then install ‍`xkblayout-state`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libx11-dev git
$ mkdir temp
$ cd temp
$ git clone https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state.git
$ cd xkblayout-state
$ make
$ make install
```

now you have to make new file `key.sh` in safe path where you don't rename this or parent folders with this content:

Don't forget replace `ir` with your lang like `sv`:
#!/bin/bash

```
outkbd=$(xkblayout-state print "%s")
uskbd="us"
#echo $outkbd

if [[ "$outkbd" == "$uskbd" ]]
then
#echo "us" switch to ir
setxkbmap ir,us
else
#echo "ir" witch to us
setxkbmap us,ir

fi
```

Now make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x key.sh
```

Finally define new shortcut for this and use it in your ide like this:
[image]